# Elastic Search Error in Executing query

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried executing following query using elastic search

```
http://192.168.110.127:9200/testingrepo/logfiles/_search?pretty



{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
                 'query': {
                            'query_string': {
                                        'query': 'request: WORD'
                              }
                   },
            "filter" : {
                "range" : {
                    "date" : {
                        "gte" : 1400376899.0,
                        "lte"  : 1400722499.0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but i am getting an error

```
{
   "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[BKeGm20mTPyDPn1iIipjrg][testingrepo][3]: SearchParseException[[testingrepo][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{ "query" : { "filtered" : { 'query': { 'query_string': { 'query': "request:WORD" } }, "filter" : { "range" : { "date" : { "gte" : 1400376899.0, "lte" : 1400722499.0 } } } } } }]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[testingrepo] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name at [Source: [B@21668a99; line: 4, column: 14]]; }{[BKeGm20mTPyDPn1iIipjrg][testingrepo][0]: SearchParseException[[testingrepo][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{ "query" : { "filtered" : { 'query': { 'query_string': { 'query': "request:WORD" } }, "filter" : { "range" : { "date" : { "gte" : 1400376899.0, "lte" : 1400722499.0 } } } } } }]]];
```

i am not sure what is going wrong. tried various combination Same Query work in pyelasticsearch client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the single quotes `'` in the `filtered` query section with double quotes `"`. That is the reason for the error you are receiving. Try this:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
                 "query": {
                            "query_string": {
                                        "query": "request: WORD"
                              }
                   },
            "filter" : {
                "range" : {
                    "date" : {
                        "gte" : 1400376899.0,
                        "lte"  : 1400722499.0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Query parsing error is generated because of "\n" and whitespace characters. You need to remove line breaks and whitespaces in order to use this query from command line with CURL for example.